# Passing an escaped String to JQuery($)-Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

currently I am trying to highlight elements on a page. Therefore I pass a comma seperate String to a Javascript-Funktion called highlight.

```
highlight("main:box1,main:box2");
```

This was working fine till I found ids with : on the page. So I tried to escape them with a little regex. Here things started to get a little funny.

If I escape the string by replacing : with \: the jQuery-Function does not work anymore.

```
var string = value.replace(/:/g, "\\\\:");
jQuery("#" + string).css("color", "red");
```

If I replace main: with "" and write main\: in the jQuery-Function everything works fine.

```
var string = value.replace(/main:/g, "");
jQuery("#main\\:" + string).css("color", "red");
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the jQuery-Function not except my escaped string?

Help needed :-(

Example-Code attached: http://db.tt/0FLRlM

Thanks Jan

Answer (score 1):

You're double escaping the `\` in your first attempt at substitution. What you've done is replace `:` with `\\:`, even though you're probably seeing `\:` when you output it.

Comment: To be explicit, use `var string = value.replace(/:/g, "\\:");`